# I want to convert pyspark dataframe to specific JSON string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have following sample data :

```
+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----------------+---------+
|selcn1|selcn2|selcn3|var1|var2|var3|           selarr|   vararr|
+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----------------+---------+
|   one| three|   two|   1|   3|   2|[one, three, two]|[1, 3, 2]|
| three|   one|   two|   3|   1|   2|[three, one, two]|[3, 1, 2]|
|   two|  null|   one|   2|   3|   1|      [two,, one]|[2, 3, 1]|
+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----------------+---------+
```

I want to convert this to following JSON structure for each row, then store in seperate column, it should be sorted based on key, and if there's null in key, there should not be any entry for it in JSON (e.g third row) :

```
first row : [{"key":"one","value":"1"},{"key":"two","value":"2"}{"key":"three","value":"3"}]
second row : [{"key":"one","value":"1"},{"key":"two","value":"2"}{"key":"three","value":"3"}]
third row : [{"key":"one","value":"1"},{"key":"three","value":"3"}]
```

I have tried this, but unable to sort and skip entries not having keys :

```
structure = F.array([  struct(col('selcn1').alias('key') , col('var1').alias('value')   ),struct(col('selcn2').alias('key') , col('var2').alias('value')   ), struct(col('selcn3').alias('key') , col('var3').alias('value')   )      ])

df2.withColumn('temp',to_json(structure)).select('temp').show(23,False)

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|temp                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"key":"one","value":"1"},{"key":"three","value":"3"},{"key":"two","value":"2"}]|
|[{"key":"three","value":"3"},{"key":"one","value":"1"},{"key":"two","value":"2"}]|
|[{"key":"two","value":"2"},{"value":"3"},{"key":"one","value":"1"}]              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't get the sorting part you mentioned. Do you want the JSON entries to get sorted? What's the sorting order here?

Answer (score 0):

***NB.** In your sample, your keys are words and not sorted as words but numbers i.e. when sorting words `three` will appear before `two` as `h` appears before `w` in the alphabet.*

If your actual dataset does not intend to sort numerical words then you may try the following:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2=(
    df.withColumn(
        "json",
        F.to_json(
            F.filter(
                F.array_sort(
                    F.array([ F.expr("struct(selcn{0} as key, var{0} as value)".format(i))  for i in range(1,4)])
                ),
                lambda rcol : rcol.getField("key").isNotNull()
            )
        )
    )
)
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

```
root
 |-- selcn1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- selcn2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- selcn3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- var1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- var2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- var3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- selarr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- vararr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- json: string (nullable = true)

+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|selcn1|selcn2|selcn3|var1|var2|var3|selarr           |vararr   |json                                                                             |
+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|one   |three |two   |1   |3   |2   |[one, three, two]|[1, 3, 2]|[{"key":"one","value":"1"},{"key":"three","value":"3"},{"key":"two","value":"2"}]|
|three |one   |two   |3   |1   |2   |[three, one, two]|[3, 1, 2]|[{"key":"one","value":"1"},{"key":"three","value":"3"},{"key":"two","value":"2"}]|
|two   |null  |one   |2   |3   |1   |[two, , one]     |[2, 3, 1]|[{"key":"one","value":"1"},{"key":"two","value":"2"}]                            |
+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In the code above

1. `F.array([ F.expr("struct(selcn{0} as key, var{0} as value)".format(i))  for i in range(1,4)])` creates an array of `structs` with the desired `key` and `value`. The shorthand approach is achieved using python list comprehension and sparks [`expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html) which parses the sql expression to generate the desired struct
2. [array_sort](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_sort.html) is then used to sort the array. NB. Sorting in spark is in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)
3. [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html) is then used to filter out structs with `null` keys. You may adjust this lambda function (`lambda rcol : rcol.getField("key").isNotNull()`) as desired to adjust your filter
4. [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html) is then used to convert the filtered result to JSON

Let me know if this works for your use case or you can share additional samples to help to replicate your use case.

**Additional References**

- Pyspark [array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html)
- Pyspark [expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html)